# bash - remove improper words

Tags: linux, bash, spell-checking

I have a file with bunch of words in  which many of them don't make much sense such as '`completemakes`' or even `#s mixed with letters/words`. What I need is to use a tool to spell check them, if it exists on the dictionary leave it, if not delete it.

What would be a good way of doing this in bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can script [Aspell.](http://aspell.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I had some fun with getting a single quote character in here, but hey, it should be as hard to read as it was to write, right? (assuming your words are listed in words.txt)

```
awk 'system("grep -i -q " "'"'"'^"$0"$'"'"'" " /usr/share/dict/words") == 0 {print $0};' words.txt
```

Comment: Just to clarify, assuming awk is processing the line "some#bad Word", then that grossly quoted term will evaluate to '^some#bad Word$' when it is passed to grep. I know, it's horrible, and I'm ashamed for putting it up on the interwebs, but in some ways, it's quite beautiful as well.

Comment: My eyes! They burns! `awk 'system("grep -i -q " "^" $0 "$" " /usr/share/dict/words") == 0 {print $0}' words.txt`

Comment: @Dennis does that deal with spaces or # characters correctly? I tried something like that which is why I ended up surrounding $0 with single quotes.

Comment: One of these might handle that better: `awk 'system("grep -i -q " "\047^" $0 "$\047" " /usr/share/dict/words") == 0 {print $0}'` or `awk -v sq="'" 'system("grep -i -q " sq "^" $0 "$" sq " /usr/share/dict/words") == 0 {print $0}'`